# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php

echo form_open('email/sent');

echo form_label('Name');

echo form_input('name');

echo "<br>";

echo form_label('From');

echo form_input('from');

echo "<br>";

echo form_label('Subject');

echo form_input('subject');

echo "<br>";

echo form_label('Message');

$data = array(

'name' => 'textarea',

'rows' => $,

'cols' => 32

);


echo form_textarea($data);

echo "<br>";

echo form_submit('submit','Sent email');

echo form_close();


?>
```

Comment: what is 'rows' => $,? you may forget to write name of variable!

Comment: `'rows' => $,` what is row supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(

'name' => 'textarea',

'rows' => '',

'cols' => 32

);
```

Give some value for rows. That should be a variable with value or static value.

Comment: Update as answer is correct :)